# How do I configure one SQL Server to connect to another, so it appears query data is coming from only one connection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbeaver

Somewhere recently I read of a method to connect one SQL Server to another, so clients could connect and run queries that appeared to come only from the first server. I cannot remember the proper terminology for this technique, and Google searches have not helped. I thought it was called "external connection", or "external source", but I cannot find this again.

Have I remembered correctly, and can someone give me an overview how to do this..?

To explain further, my preferred SQL client `DBeaver` only allows one connection in each query. As such, if I wish to join tables from two different servers, there's no direct way to do it...except perhaps this method which I can't remember how to do.

Comment: Looking for "Linked Servers"? if yes, take a look at this https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: Bingo..!! Thank you. If you create an answer based on your comment, I'll mark it as the solution so you get the reps for it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the linked server in MsSQL.

https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: It was my pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use DBVisualizer instead of Dbeaver, if you are on Linux.

Comment: Sorry, not on Linux.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33219225)

Comment: DBVisualizer on Windows displays linked servers too